# UIbutton not responding to touch

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have this view hierarchy:
[image]

The three buttons don't response. They are enabled, just when I touch there, they don't do anything (not even change their gradient/tint) which tells me they are not even received the touches. Is there something I am doing wrong?
Thanks

User interaction is enabled on all the buttons' superviews, and the buttons themselves. The buttons are also enabled.

Comment: what's the View at the bottom of the list?

Comment: A random view outside of view controller's view's hierarchy. I am not using it at the moment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using any imageViews on top or containing the UIButtons? If so, sometimes, those absorb the touches because they have the `userInteraction` boolean set to `NO` by default. Maybe even getting rid of your gradient imageView (for the time being) to determine if those are causing the issues.

If not, I would set a breakpoint on the viewDidLoad method of the superview and type in `[self.view recursiveDescription]`. It should give you at-a-glance overview of what's around those buttons and might be stealing the touches.

Good luck!

Comment: Aaargh thank you. Been driving myself nuts with this for half an hour.

Comment: +1 for great tips on UIButton inside the UIImageView. But where did you get the recursiveDescription, I think its not a standard method. Rather we can use "po x.subViews" or .superView.

Comment: `recursiveDescription` is not documented but is outlined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION34).